# Local Notification every Day at specific Time in android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

In My project need to show notification Every Day at 2 pm

I have no idea about setting time interval for repeated notification every day

My main Activity code set a time interval

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(Splash.this ,JobsNotification.class);     
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Splash.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,26);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,15);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis() , AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pendingIntent);
```

**Service for Notification**

```
public class JobsNotification extends Service 
   {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
       super.onCreate();
    }

   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
   {
       super.onStart(intent, startId);

       String strTitle="10 New Jobs Posted Today";


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.dailyjob)
            .setContentTitle(strTitle)
            .setContentText("");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, Notify.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(Notify.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
      mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
     //  Uri notificationtune = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
     //  Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notificationtune);
     //  r.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Please Help me about setting notification every day at only specific time

Thanks in Advance

Comment: is it setting up the notification for single time?

Answer (score -3):

Every day at 2 when notification arrives, set notification for the next day...
This is the only way you can achieve everlasting notifications :)

Comment: Thank for replay; i am not understanding about setting repeated alarm, and at not my notification is coming every Launch of the app